Evaluate the definite trigonometric integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{1+b\cos(x)}, $ $b \in (0,1)$

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{1+b\cos(x)}, \qquad b \in (0,1)$$

Firstly, I defined $$\tilde{f}(z)=z^{-1}\frac{(\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i})^2}{1+b\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}}=\frac{2z^{-1}}{-4}\frac{(z-z^{-1})^2}{2+bz+bz^{-1}}=-\frac{z^{-1}}{2}\frac{z^2-2+z^{-2}}{2+bz+bz^{-1}}; \quad A=\left\{0,-\frac{1}{b} \pm \frac{\sqrt{1-b^2}}{b}\right\} .$$
We have $A \cap D(0,1)= \left\{\{0,-\frac{1}{b}+\frac{\sqrt{1-b^2}}{b}\}\right\}$, and I obtained:
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{1+b\cos(x)}
&=2\pi (\operatorname{res}(0,\tilde{f})+\operatorname{res}\left(-\frac{1}{b}+\frac{\sqrt{1-b^2}}{b},\tilde{f}\right) \\
&=2\pi\left(\frac{1}{b^2}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\left(\left(-\frac{1}{b}+\frac{\sqrt{1-b^2}}{b}\right)^2-2+\left((-\frac{1}{b}+\frac{\sqrt{1-b^2}}{b}\right)^{-2}\right)}{2b\left(-\frac{1}{b}+\frac{\sqrt{1-b^2}}{b}\right)+2}\right) \\
&=2\pi\left(\frac{1}{b^2}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\left(\left(-\frac{1}{b}+\frac{\sqrt{1-b^2}}{b}\right)^2-2+\left(-\frac{1}{b}+\frac{\sqrt{1-b^2}}{b}\right)^{-2}\right)}{2\sqrt{1-b^2}}\right)
\end{align}
But it seems that I'm overcomplicating this calculation; any suggestions?

$f(\cos(x),\sin(x))=\frac{\sin^2(x)}{1+b\cos(x)}$ and defining
$\tilde{f}(z)=z^{-1}f(\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2} , \frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i})$, I guess we should obtain the equality referring to the integral

Have you tried using the half-angle substitution to rationalize the integrand?

Do you have to use Complex Analysis? Because, Integral Calculator seems to do the job with Weierstrass substitution

@SayanDutta. May I suggest you use "the tangent half-angle substitution" since Euler used it fifty years before  Weierstrass was born.

My book that sets this problem: $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin^2 \theta d \theta}{a+b \cos \theta}$ for $0<b<a$ to be solved with complex contour integral says the answer should be $\frac{2 \pi (a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2})}{b^2}$.

With a combination of simple transformations, we can simplify the integral somewhat before applying the residue theorem:
$$\begin{align*}
I(b) &= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin^2x}{1+b\cos x} \, dx \\
&= \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\sin^2x}{1-b\cos x} \, dx & x\to x+\pi\\
&= 2 \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin^2x}{1-b\cos x} \, dx \\
&= 2 \left\{\int_{-\tfrac\pi2}^0+\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\right\} \frac{\cos^2x}{1-b\sin x} \, dx & \left\{\begin{matrix}x\to x+\frac\pi2, \\ \text{split at }x=0\end{matrix}\right. \\
&= 2 \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \cos^2x \left(\frac1{1+b\sin x} + \frac1{1-b\sin x}\right) \, dx & x\to-x\\
&= 4 \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{\cos^2x}{1-b^2\sin^2x} \, dx \\
&= 4 \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2-b^2+b^2\cos(2x)} \, dx \\
&= \frac{2\pi}{b^2} - \frac{8(1-b^2)}{b^2} \underbrace{\int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{dx}{2-b^2+b^2\cos(2x)}}_{=: J(b)} \\
&= \boxed{2\pi \frac{1-\sqrt{1-b^2}}{b^2}} \\[2ex]
\hline
J(b) &= \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{dx}{2-b^2+b^2\cos(2x)} \\
&= \frac12 \int_0^\pi \frac{dx}{2-b^2+b^2\cos x} & x\to \frac x2 \tag{$\diamondsuit$} \\
&= \frac12 \int_{-\pi}^0 \frac{dx}{2-b^2+b^2\cos x} & x\to-x \tag{$\spadesuit$} \\
&= \frac14 \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{dx}{2-b^2+b^2\cos x} & \frac{(\diamondsuit)+(\spadesuit)}2 \\
&= \frac14 \cdot i2\pi \cdot \frac2{ib^2} \underset{z_0}{\operatorname{Res}} f(z) & \text{res. thm. }\left(z=e^{ix}\right) \\
&= \frac\pi{4\sqrt{1-b^2}}
\end{align*}$$
where $f(z)=\dfrac1{1 + \frac{4-2b^2}{b^2} z+z^2}$ has one pole inside $\lvert z\rvert=1$ at $z_0=\dfrac{b^2-2+2\sqrt{1-b^2}}{b^2}$. (The magnitude of the other pole with the negative square root will always exceed $1$.)

Nice answer, I like it so much (+1)

\begin{align*}
\tilde{f} (z) = - \frac{1}{2 z^2} \frac{(z^2-1)^2}{bz^2+2z+b}
\end{align*}
Expanding around $z=0$ gives:
\begin{align*}
- \frac{1}{2 b z^2} \frac{1-2z^2+z^4}{1 + 2\frac{z}{b} + z^2} = - \frac{1}{2 b z^2} (1-2z^2+z^4) [1-(2\frac{z}{b} + z^2)+\cdots] = - \frac{1}{2bz^2} + \frac{1}{b^2z} + \cdots
\end{align*}
We have
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin^2x}{1+b\cos x} dx & = 2\pi \frac{1}{b^2} - 2 \pi \lim_{z \rightarrow -\frac{1}{b} + \frac{\sqrt{1-b^2}}{b}} (z + \frac{1}{b} - \frac{\sqrt{1-b^2}}{b}) \frac{1}{2 b z^2} \frac{(z^2-1)^2}{z^2+2z+\frac{1}{b}}
\nonumber \\
& = 2\pi \frac{1}{b^2} - 2 \pi \lim_{z \rightarrow -\frac{1}{b} + \frac{\sqrt{1-b^2}}{b}} \frac{1}{2 b z^2} \frac{(z^2-1)^2}{z + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{\sqrt{1-b^2}}{b}}
\nonumber \\
& = 2\pi \frac{1}{b^2} - \frac{\pi}{2} \lim_{z \rightarrow -\frac{1}{b} + \frac{\sqrt{1-b^2}}{b}} \frac{1}{z^2} \frac{(z^2-1)^2}{\sqrt{1-b^2}}
\end{align*}
When $z=\frac{1}{b} (-1+\sqrt{1-b^2})$:
\begin{align*}
z^2 -1 & = \frac{1}{b^2} (2-b^2 - 2 \sqrt{1-b^2} - b^2) = \frac{2}{b^2}\sqrt{1-b^2}  (-1+\sqrt{1-b^2})
\end{align*}
So when $z=\frac{1}{b} (-1+\sqrt{1-b^2})$:
\begin{align*}
\frac{(z^2 -1)^2}{z^2 \sqrt{1-b^2}} & = \frac{4}{b^4} (1-b^2) (-1+\sqrt{1-b^2})^2 \cdot \frac{b^2}{(-1+\sqrt{1-b^2})^2} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-b^2}}
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{4\sqrt{1-b^2}}{b^2}
\end{align*}
Putting it all together:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin^2x}{1+b\cos x} dx = 2 \pi \frac{1-\sqrt{1-b^2}}{b^2}  .
\end{align*}
Which agrees with the answer in my book.

$$\frac{\sin^2x}{1+b\cos x}=\frac{b^2-1}{b^2}\frac1{1+b\cos x}+\frac1{b^2}(1-b\cos x)$$
and
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac1{1+b\cos x}dx=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1-b^2}}$$
is the quickest way.

We have $${\sin^2x\over 1+b\cos x}={1-\cos^2x\over 1+b\cos x}\\
={b^2-1\over b^2}{1\over 1+b\cos x}+{1\over b^2}(1-b\cos x)$$
It is well known that for $|r|<1$ we have $${1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_0^{2\pi}{1-r^2\over 1-2r\cos x+r^2}\,dx=1$$ as
$${1-r^2\over 1-2r\cos x+r^2}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty r^{|n|}e^{inx}$$ Let $r$ satisfies $b=-2r/(1+r^2),$ i.e.
$r=-(1-\sqrt{1-b^2})/b.$  Then
$${1\over 1+b\cos x}= {1+r^2\over 1-2r\cos x+r^2}$$
Thus
$$\int\limits_0^{2\pi}{1\over 1+b\cos x}\,dx=2\pi{1+r^2\over 1-r^2} $$ Hence
$$\int\limits_0^{2\pi}{\sin^2x\over 1+b\cos x}\,dx=2\pi{b^2-1\over b^2}{1+r^2\over 1-r^2}+{2\pi\over b^2}$$
It suffices to plug in the value of $r$ to obtain the result.

One can avoid dealing with radicals until the last step by setting $\alpha := \arcsin b$, so that the integrand is
$$f(z) := \frac{i}{2} \cdot \frac{(z^2 - 1)^2}{z^2 (\sin \alpha \cdot z^2 + \sin \alpha + 2 z)} .$$
The poles of the integrand lie at
$0, \pm \cot \alpha -\csc \alpha$, of which only $0$ and $z_\alpha := \cot \alpha - \csc \alpha$ are inside the contour. Then, calculating directly and applying standard trig identities gives simple expressions for the leading terms of the Laurent expansions (the corresponding residues are boxed):
\begin{array}{ll}
\hline
\textrm{pole} & \textrm{Laurent series} \\
\hline
z = 0 \qquad & f \sim \frac12 \csc \alpha \cdot z^{-2} + \boxed{(- i \csc^2 \alpha)} z^{-1} + \cdots \\
z = z_\alpha & f \sim \boxed{i \csc \alpha \cot \alpha} (z - z_\alpha)^{-1} + 
\cdots. \\
\hline
\end{array}

So, the Residue Theorem gives that the integral has value \begin{align}\oint_C f \,dz &= 2 \pi i [\operatorname{Res}(f, 0) + \operatorname{Res}(f, z_\alpha)]\\ &= 2 \pi i (-i \csc^2 \alpha + \csc \alpha \cot \alpha) \\ &= \frac{2 \pi (1 - \cos \alpha)}{\sin^2 \alpha} \\ &= \boxed{\frac{2\pi \left(1 - \sqrt{1 - b^2}\right)}{b^2} = \frac{2\pi}{1 + \sqrt{1 - b^2}}} .\end{align}

Alternatively, periodicity gives that the integral is equal to the integral of the same function over $[-\pi, \pi]$, and then applying the tangent half-angle substitution $x = \tan \frac{t}{2}$ rationalizes the integral, yielding
$$8 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{t^2 \,dt}{(1 + t^2)^2 ((1 - b) t^2 + b + 1)} ,$$ so we can proceed as usual with the partial fraction decomposition. Writing $b = \frac{c^2 - 1}{c^2 + 1}$ makes the decomposition a little pleasant to work out and gives
$$4 (1 + c^2) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{t^2 \,dt}{(1 + t^2)^2 (c^2 + t^2)} = \frac{2 \pi (1 + c^2)}{(1 + c)^2} .$$

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iverson}[1]{\left[\left[\,{#1}\,\right]\right]}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\left.\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\sin^{2}\pars{x} \over 1 + b\cos\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\right\vert_{b\ \in\ \pars{0,1}}} =
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\sin^{2}\pars{x} \over 1 - b\cos\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = & \
2\int_{0}^{\pi}{\sin^{2}\pars{x} \over
1 - b\cos\pars{x}}\,\dd x =
2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}{\cos^{2}\pars{x} \over
1 + b\sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = & \
4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\cos^{2}\pars{x} \over
1 - b^{2}\sin^{2}\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = & \
{4 \over b^{2}}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\dd x -
4\,{1 - b^{2} \over b^{2}}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\dd x \over 1 - b^{2}\sin^{2}\pars{x}}
\\[5mm] = & \
{2\pi \over b^{2}} -
4\,{1 - b^{2} \over b^{2}}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{\sec^{2}\pars{x} \over \sec^{2}\pars{x} - b^{2}\tan^{2}\pars{x}}\dd x
\\[5mm] = & \
{2\pi \over b^{2}} -
4\,{1 - b^{2} \over b^{2}}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{\sec^{2}\pars{x} \over
\pars{1 - b^{2}}\tan^{2}\pars{x} + 1}\dd x
\\[5mm] = & \
{2\pi \over b^{2}} -
4\,{1 - b^{2} \over b^{2}}{1 \over \root{1 - b^{2}}}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{\root{1 - b^{2}}\sec^{2}\pars{x} \over
\bracks{\root{1 - b^{2}}\tan\pars{x}}^{2} + 1}\dd x
\\[5mm] & \sr{\root{1 - b^{2}}\tan\pars{x}\ \mapsto\ x}{\LARGE =}\quad
{2\pi \over b^{2}} -
4\,{\root{1 - b^{2}} \over b^{2}}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x^{2} + 1}}^{\ds{\pi/2}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\bbx{\color{#44f}{{1 - \root{1 - b^{2}} \over b^{2}}2\pi\,,\quad\color{black}{b \in \pars{0,1}}}}
\end{align}
